# Akka.Net ConsistentHashing router as a load balancer for in memory data object

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have huge in memory object and I am just wondering, if I can create a ConsistentHashing router and be able split load to underling actors.
The main problem is that I need to ingest actors with data after creation, so just wondering how I can achieve that.
The master object has a good number of records, which will be grouped by Id field.

This is my ideas:

1. when actor is created - can I get it's hashPool to retrieve required ids from master object?
2. when actor is created I can wrap ingestion message ConsistentHashableEnvelope  and then when queering using same wrap to ask for data- will this work?

[reference](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers)

Comment: Hmm...not sure I understand entirely what you're trying to do. Would this large in-memory object be shared by the actors (read and write)? In this case you come back to the problem of shared mutable state which kind of defeats the purpose of using an actor system. If this object is read-only then you will be able to do what you're planning, but it's still not ideal. A better way would be to have each actor have an internal "slice" of this object which only belongs to it, and share no state with the other actors in the hashing pool.

Comment: Hi,  probably my explanation wasn't good enough,  but my goal is to split this into slices and I am not sure how I can ingest actors and then be able to serve data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on your question, I understand better what you're trying to do.

I've done something similar, but slightly different in the way the actors have to start up: a caching system where I use a user's ID in a `ConsistentHashableEnvelope` to route the request to the actor that should hadndle that user's request. If the user's data isn't available, it is loaded into memory from a third-party service. All following requests will operate on this data in memory.

In your case I'd tackle the problem in this manner:

- Setup your `ConsistentHashing` router with actors that startup in a state that can `Receive<>` the individual entries they need.
- Simply `Tell()` the router all the individual entries in this large object you want to slice up using a `ConsistentHashableEnvelope` as a wrapper, and the router will send each entry to its correct destination.
- In the actors, `Receive<>` the entries and use some method to merge the received data into the existing internal structure. This means that when the actor first starts up it will simply store the slices and if it receives entries later on you can decide what to do (replace, update, whatever you wish).
- When handing off subsequest messages to the router, *always* make sure you're using the correct key `ConsistentHashableEnvelope`, otherwise the message will be routed to an actor that doesn't have the data!

From your post I don't know much about the rest of your project requirements, but if you need to be able to first populate the actors with their slices before handling other requests that depend on this data, you may want to start the routees in an `AwaitingData` state using `Become()`, and then move them to a `Ready` state once their data has been received.

If you add more info about your project I may be able to help you some more.